# Как удалить данные в двух связанных таблицах (связь многие ко многим) одним запросом?

Tags: sql, many-to-many, delete, многие-ко-многим

Есть таблицы `films`, `actors` и связывающая их таблица `films_actors`.
Код CREATE

```
CREATE TABLE `actors` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`surname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=9
;

CREATE TABLE `films` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`release` SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL,
`format` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6
;
CREATE TABLE `films_actors` (
`id_film` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`id_actor` INT(11) NOT NULL,
INDEX `FK_films_actors_actors` (`id_actor`),
INDEX `FK_films_actors_films` (`id_film`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_films_actors_actors` FOREIGN KEY (`id_actor`) REFERENCES `actors` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_films_actors_films` FOREIGN KEY (`id_film`) REFERENCES `films` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Если я удалю данные из талибы `actors` или `films`, то автоматически данные удалятся из таблицы `films_actors`, вопрос в том можно ли одним запросом удалить данные из всех трех таблиц разом?

Вот запрос который я пытался написать, но безуспешно.

```
delete
from films, actors
where actors.id in (
select films_actors.id_actor from films_actors 
where films_actors.id_film = 5
) and films.id = films_actors.id_film
```

Comment: А какой смысл ? Вы действительно хотите удалить все фильмы, в которых участвовал хоть один актер, задействованный в фильме N5 ? И что делать тогда с актерами, которые участвовали в тех фильмах их то же удалить вместе с остальными их фильмами ? тогда это фактически равноценно полному удалению всей БД

Comment: Я наверное не совсем точно объяснил. Мне нужно просто удалить фильм и весь актерский состав этого фильма. В любом случае решение уже найдено.

Comment: Но очевидно, что так делать нельзя. Вы скажем удаляете фильм "А зори здесь тихие", и заодно удаляете актера "Андрей Мартынов", который в нем играл. Но ведь этот актер снялся в еще нескольких десятках фильмов и из них он тоже будет удален !

Comment: А ты прав друг.

Comment: В общем я бы свел задачу все таки к двум запросам: 1. удалить фильм. 2. удалить актеров, которые не участвуют ни в одном фильме. Хотя лично я бы так то же не делал, если об актере хранится не только ФИО. вполне возможно, что он потребуется в будущем и надо будет заново заводить все данные о нем...

Comment: Пожалуй соглашусь с последним вариантом. Просто думал что незачем хранить данные об актере если он не снимался ни в одном фильме.